# "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send." when build a project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My laptop died and I switched to the new one. Get code from source control, but have to reinstall all NuGet packages. Now when I try to build the project I get "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send." I use VS 2015.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: if you are working in an org and if it has any custom registries/nuget sources, make  sure you have those nuget sources added in VS or nuget.config. Also consider checking any proxy configurations required.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` issue.

My assumption is that you are targeting a differnt framework then the one you had before. In .NET 4.6 and above. You don’t need to do any additional work to support TLS 1.2, it’s supported by default. try to open it in visual studio and it will detect it for you.

Comment: Unfortunate not. It is on the build stage.  No code executed yet.

Comment: I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

OK I got it just in 10 minutes after posting the question... Folder .nuget was missed from source control and VS tried to get NuGet.exe file (I have the settings "Download NuGet.exe if it does not already exist" enabled) but looks like it cannot for some reason. I copied NuGet.exe from another project and it resolve it.